# How to get value from logger's scope

Tags: c#, scope, ilogger

I am using `ILogger`'s `BeginScope` extension to fill it with all sorts of interesting ids.

Is it possible to get some value from the logger's scope? For example `correlation-id` to add it to HTTP header.